# c# how to output Unicode characters?

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, console

I have int values stored in a list, that I want to output as unicode characters, like this:

```
 //A List<int> named Kanji exists and has values
    Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < Kanji.Count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((char)Kanji[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

But this only returns ? characters. What should I do? The int values themselves are fine, I tested them.

Comment: If it only returns ? then you need to have Japanese language packs installed or active in your solution - something to do with the unicode character not displaying correctly

Comment: This actually has very little to do with C#; google around on how to make the console work correctly with unicode - it doesn't support it "out of the box", and your application has very little control over most of the reasons why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console is probably not using a Unicode or Japanese encoding, and/or the font used does not contain the required character glyphs.

Have a look at [`Console.OutputEncoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.outputencoding(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information, and the [Unicode Support for the Console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx#Unicode) section.

Comment: His code shows `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;`, so I assume the "or" part of your comment is the only relevant part: "or the font used does not contain the required character glyphs".

Comment: The page I link to lists all the caveats, such as supporting UTF16 (which `Encoding.Unicode` is) only from .NET 4.5 onward, and that the console must use a TrueType font with the required glyphs... so if .NET 4.0 or earlier is being used as target framework, only UTF8 would be supported.

Comment: _"In general, the console reads input and writes output by using the current console code page, which the system locale defines by default. A code page can handle only a subset of available Unicode characters, so if you try to display characters that are not mapped by a particular code page, the console won't be able to display all characters or represent them accurately"_

Comment: Thank you Lucero, stuartd and Luaan, the problem was with the console itself.