# Converting from UTF8 to ISO-8859-1 doesn't work

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I would like to convert a string variable from UTF8 to ISO-8859-1, because for special character like ä,ö,ü, I see `?` in C#. To achieve this goal, I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922199/c-sharp-convert-string-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-latin1-h/24453606#24453606). But it does not work for me. I have tried to find out why....

I have observed the bytes of original and converted string in C# with this code:

```
 System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
 System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
 formatter.Serialize(stream, dt2.Rows[0][0]); // I read my string from a datatable and it is utf8 encoded
  byte[] bytes = stream.GetBuffer();
```

This line of code:

```
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", ""));
```

returns:

```
4652495343484BEFBFBD53455A55424552454954554E47454E2020
```

Now, I would like to encode to ISO-8859-1. For this, I use this code:

```
var srcEncoding = Encoding.Default;   // The original bytes are utf8 hence here "Default"
var destEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
var destBytes = Encoding.Convert(srcEncoding, destEncoding, bytes);
```

and then run the line of code:

```
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(destBytes).Replace("-", ""));
```

I get the same hex code. It seems that the conversion doesn't work properly

```
4652495343484BEFBFBD53455A55424552454954554E47454E2020
```

Do you have any idea why the conversion doesn't work for me?

Comment: Eight bit ASCII contains character 0x00 to 0x7f which is display the same for all encoding methods.  Character 0x80 to 0xFF are displayed different depending on encoding used.  So there is no conversion needed.  The bytes are the same for all 8 bit encoding methods.

Comment: What should I do then to get the right chars like ä,ö,ü,... If I do no conversion, then still see ? or another things for these chars

Comment: @jdweng: There's a multibyte sequence thrown in there, `EFBFBD`, which appears to be a valid UTF-8 encoding of `\uFFFD`

Comment: @Kaja: Have you tried with `srcEncoding = Encoding.UTF8` ?  Using `Encoding.Default` just makes it harder to tell if the code is correct.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes but doesnt help me and still see ? instead of ä

Comment: If I change it to utf8, as you said, I get this hex: `4652495343484B3F53455A55424552454954554E47454E2020` there is not ä in it.

Comment: Your input string doesn't contain a-umlaut.  It contains ["Unicode replacement character"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm)  Whatever conversion happened before the data was stored has already lost your a-umlaut.

Comment: @BenVoigt sure I have ä in my text. Actually my string come from sqlite database. in my DB Browser for this string if I encoded my column to `CP850` then I see ä

Comment: @Ben Voigt : 16 bit is unicode and not 8 bit encoding.

Comment: @Kaja: Then your database reading code is wrong.  But `bytes` does not contain a-umlaut.

Comment: @jdweng: I don't understand what you are trying to say.  His `byte[] bytes` contains UTF-8 encoding of a bunch of ASCII with one UTF-8 encoding of "Unicode replacement character" mixed in.

Comment: You usually can't change encoding once bytes have been encoded to string.  The encoding will remove characters that are not valid (like ascii encoding removes non printable character).  Usually character aren't display properly because of the method you are using to view the string.  Like Console encoding will default to the language in the computer settings and may not show properly.  Also the font being used may not display character properly.

Comment: why would you want to convert? UTF-8 can store every possible characters. And if it doesn't print correctly then it's the fault of the console or the printing function. This is an XY problem. See [Outputting a Unicode character in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3162116/995714), [How to write Unicode characters to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5750203/995714), [c# how to output Unicode characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40364627/995714)

Comment: @phuclv: He doesn't have the right UTF-8 string to begin with.  What he does have, is stored in the database in CP850 and then turned into a mess by the database access library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string doesn't contain a-umlaut.

It contains ["Unicode replacement character"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).

Whatever conversion happened before you got `byte[] bytes` has already lost your a-umlaut.

Comment: please see my last post [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/681a2c71-8417-484a-bf63-58d6a2d05d79/retrieving-special-characters-from-sqlite-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral). I can see ä

Comment: If i run the query `SELECT hex(c1) FROM t1 where c2=338` then I get this hex: `4652495343484B8E53455A55424552454954554E47454E2020`

Comment: @Kaja: Then the first for lines of code for retrieving the "original" are not working.  Because the result of those four lines has "Unicode Replacement Character" not a-umlaut.

Comment: Do you have any Idea how can Iget the original bytes in C#?

Comment: Do you see a difference between that string and the one in your question?  Because I do.  They aren't even the same length, and your SELECT query result doesn't contain `EFBFBD` which is the UTF-8 encoding of the replacement character.

Comment: You are right. Is it a bug in c#, that I can not get original bytes?

Comment: @Kaja: That's a database question not a string conversion question.  It might be a bug in the SQLite library you are using.  I have no idea.

Comment: my last question: How do you see this one, can I get from this hex, the right string with ä: `A4652495343484BC28E53455A55424552454954554E47454E2020`

Comment: @Kaja: Is that in a byte array? Try `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(array)`.  If you have a string containing the hex representation, first [use `SoapHexBinary.Parse` as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2556329/103167) to get the array.

Comment: Actually I have changed the connection string. Originaly I had such a con string:`Data Source=C:\Test\test.001;UseUTF8Encoding=True` then I have changed my con to `Data Source=C:\Test\test.001;UseUTF16Encoding=True;Synchronous=Normal;New=False` as you can see I have changed utf8 to utf16 and bytes which you see in my last post are from utf16

Comment: I'm positive those aren't UTF-16.  They look like raw CP850.

Comment: but still cant see ä in my string. :(. I see FRISCHK?SEZUBEREITUNGEN in the consol without any conversion

Comment: Did some more research, CP850 is not compatible with ISO-8859-1.  Trying to figure out the C# name for CP850.  Might be just `Encoding.GetEncoding(850)`

Comment: Sorry for disturbing, but isn't it, if I get the bytes in CP850, then I don't need to do a conversion? I thought CP850 or 850 can show ä

Comment: @Kaja: I think I figured it out.  Your hex bytes are not "raw CP850", they are a UTF-8 transformation of CP850.  So you need to undo the UTF-8, then decode as CP850.  Demonstration: https://rextester.com/CUZBR49827

Comment: Your earlier string, the one straight from `SELECT`, was actually a bit easier to deal with since it was real raw CP850, no abused UTF-8 layer on top.

Comment: God save you! now I can see Ä, but I see some irrelevant character also: `   ????          FRISCHKÄSEZUBEREITUNGEN   ` Do you have any Idea why?

Comment: The string you gave me most recently seems to start with `0A` which is a newline character.  The result of the SELECT doesn't have that, nor the `C28E` which should be just `8E`.

Comment: Thank you so much. generally I know what should I do. Hopefully I can achieve my aim :)

Comment: what about if I would like to work with the original hex in database: `4652495343484B8E53455A55424552454954554E47454E2020` as I understand it is CP850, which contains ä. correct? That means if I would like to show ä in the console, I should only convert it into ISO-8859-1 and I dont need to convert it first to UTF8, is it correct?

Comment: For that string, just call `Encoding.GetEncoding(850).GetString(array)` immediately.  No UTF8 and certainly no ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to mess with `MemoryStream`s and `BinaryFormatter`s. Just use the methods `GetString` and `GetBytes` of the appropriate `Encoding`.

```
byte[] oldBytes = new byte[] { 0x46, 0x52, 0x49, 0x53, 0x43, 0x48,
    0x4B, 0xEF, 0xBF, 0xBD, 0x53, 0x45, 0x5A, 0x55, 0x42, 0x45, 0x52,
    0x45, 0x49, 0x54, 0x55, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x45, 0x4E, 0x20, 0x20 };
Console.WriteLine($"oldBytes: {BitConverter.ToString(oldBytes)} ({oldBytes.Length})");

string oldStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oldBytes);
Console.WriteLine($"oldStr: <{oldStr}>");

byte[] newBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(oldStr);
Console.WriteLine($"newBytes: {BitConverter.ToString(newBytes)} ({newBytes.Length})");

string newStr = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(newBytes);
Console.WriteLine($"newStr: <{newStr}>");
```

Output:

```
oldBytes: 46-52-49-53-43-48-4B-EF-BF-BD-53-45-5A-55-42-45-52-45-49-54-55-4E-47-45-4E-20-20 (27)
oldStr: <FRISCHK�SEZUBEREITUNGEN  >  
newBytes: 46-52-49-53-43-48-4B-3F-53-45-5A-55-42-45-52-45-49-54-55-4E-47-45-4E-20-20 (25)
newStr: <FRISCHK?SEZUBEREITUNGEN  >
```

Comment: "garbage in, garbage out".  Your `oldBytes` array contains "Unicode replacement character" garbage.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeap, the bytes are most probably corrupted. The [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) is a good indication that something bad happened earlier. I wanted mainly to show a simpler API for converting text to bytes and vice versa.